# How to print a vector of dequeue in row wise format

Tags: c++, vector, output, deque

**so basically I want to a print a vector of dequeue in row wise format **

like in this manner:-
0
01
012
01
0
for this I have used a double ended queue and then trying to store this dequeue in vector. But I am unable to print it.

```
vector<deque<int>>v;
int n=t+1;
auto it=v.begin();
while(n--){
    deque<int> d;
    d.push_back(t);
    for(int i=t-1;i>=0;i--){
        d.push_back(i);
        d.push_front(i);
    }

    v.push_back(d);
    v.insert(it,d);
    it++;
    
}
 int t=0;
while(t<v.size()){
    cout<<v[t]<<"\n";
    t++;
}
return 0;
```

}

So please instruct me on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to print each element of the outer vector, but those elements are deques which are not intrinsically printable:

Instead, print each integer individually and a newline after each deque:

```
for (auto& deque_of_integers : v) {
    for (auto& integer : deque_of_integers)
        cout << integer;
    cout << "\n";
}
```